# Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting a below error when i try to do the below:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%3C&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=7&p3=%7Bleft:%3Cimageid,right:%20%3Eimageid,

Controller:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    angular.forEach(document.querySelectorAll(".q"), function(val, key) {
        (function(key, val) {
         console.log(val.getAttribute("ng-class").replace(/\{{([ind]+)\}}/g, key));
      })(key, val);

    });
}
```

```css
.ng-invalid { 
    border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-class="{x:{{ind}}<id,y:{{ind}} >id, z :{{ind}} == id}" class="q"></div>
      <div ng-class="{x:{{ind}}<id,y:{{ind}} >id, z :{{ind}} == id}" class="q"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code prints fine in console replacing {{ind}} values perfectly, but when the application executes i get the below error:

> Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary expression at column 7 of the
>   expression [{x:id,] starting at [{4}].

Comment: Can you explain, what are you trying to do?

Comment: If you look at my fiddle, you could get it... i am trying to replace {{ind}} value of the div...       <div ng-class="{x:{{ind}}<id,y:{{ind}} >id, z :{{ind}} == id}" class="q"></div>

Comment: I mean the big picture - are you trying to modify `ng-class` expression while the application is running?

Comment: yup.... yes i am trying to do that... coz {{ind}} value id dynamic...

Comment: This is not a coding pattern I have ever seen. If the variable `ind` is dynamic, you don't need `{{}}` curly braces. Just use the variable as is. It's highly unlikely that anything you want to achieve requires this weird pattern.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle: The point is i am just trying to replace the {{ind}} with regular expression, in this case it does not matter whether its {{}} or plain ind.

Comment: This will not work, as far as I know, because angular does replacement magic by itself when it is constructing the DOM. so, you may have to construct your own directives and look at the [compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to achieve something like this.

Comment: Another issue is that `{{}}` interpolation is invalid syntax for `ng-class`

Comment: Appart from all correct comments above, you forgot the closing `"`after ng-class="{x:{{ind}}

Answer (score 2):

I think angular is trying to tell you that you have to pass the div as a string.